# Cannot run JHipster project right after creation

Tags: jhipster

I'm unable to get a jhipster generated project running, right after generating it.

```
~/folder$ yo jhipster
```

Complete the "wizard" then

```
~/folder$ gradle bootRun
```

Boom! It fails on the "npmInstall" step. "bower install" and "npm install" work fine by themselves.

The exceptions (when running "gradle --stacktrace bootRun")

```
 Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'npm''
at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:196)
at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.failed(DefaultExecHandle.java:325)
at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:83)
... 1 more
Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start 'npm'
at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcessLauncher.start(WrapperProcessLauncher.java:36)
at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:65)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "npm" (in directory "/<...>/workspace/netreon"): error=2, No such file or directory
at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
... 4 more
```

Npm is available on the PATH though, installed with brew

```
$ which node
/usr/local/bin/node                                                                                                                                     
$ which npm
/usr/local/bin/npm
$ node --version
v0.10.29
$ npm --version
2.5.0
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_55"
$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_55
```

.yo-rc.json configs:

```js
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "baseName": "myproj",
    "packageName": "com.myproj",
    "packageFolder": "com/myproj",
    "authenticationType": "oauth2",
    "hibernateCache": "ehcache",
    "clusteredHttpSession": "no",
    "websocket": "spring-websocket",
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "useCompass": true,
    "buildTool": "gradle",
    "frontendBuilder": "gulp",
    "javaVersion": "7"
  }
}
```

I think I have the latest version of jhipster generator, not sure how to check that though

Comment: You are supposed to use the Gradle Wrapper, not your Gradle version, maybe it's the cause of your issue?

Comment: Otherwise the error looks like an NPM installation issue, did you check the videos at https://docs.npmjs.com/ ? I had lots of issues with NPM installation too

Comment: Using the gradle wrapper causes the same issue. I did have some problems with node recently. I'm going to completely uninstall it tonight and reinstall using your link as a reference. Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: Uninstalled, cleaned and reinstalled node, still the same outcome :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you running as root using `sudo -i`? npm is rarely installed for root and that was my issue.

Just `gradlew` under your normal user